# Rich snippets for home page with last entries

Tags: rich-snippets

I've added rich snippets for single posts in a blog. My question is: what should I add to the home page with the last posts? Here the `"entry-title"` and `"entry-description"` seem to be the only two which make sense (web title and web description). Am I right?

Comment: Not sure I'm totally clear on your site, but have thought about using the [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) schema type?

Comment: @dan - Thanks for your suggestion. I've added BlogPosting schema type to the single posts, but what should I add to the home page, where some post are shown? One itemprop (or hentry) to every post? Or just the description elements for that page (e.g. "entry-title" and "entry-description")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ItemList](http://schema.org/ItemList) schema on the blog home page.  Your home page contains a list of items: blog posts.

You could also put no schema at all on your home page.   I wouldn't.   I don't see what you have to gain by finding some schema to include on every page.

Comment: Thanks, ItemList seems to be the solution, but I don't get you in your last sentence *I don't see what you have to gain by finding some schema to include on every page.* Isn't it the schema objective?

Comment: Usually the objective of using a schema is so that a program can consume the data because it is now machine readable which then benefits your website.  For example, sometimes Google will show your listing using rich snippets in the search results when you use certain schema.   When you don't know of such an advantage to using schema, it seems pointless to implement them.

Comment: So some `entry-title` and `entry-description` could make Google to show a list of entries in SERP for the home page. Isn't it?

Comment: The only time they show the list is for forum sites and the have an algorithm that identifies the threads without relying on microdata.